# Make Vim's Vundle autoupdate?

Tags: vim, plugins, vim-plugins

Is there a way to make Vundle automatically update? I'd like Vim to run `BundleUpdate` every so often, ideally in the background.

Comment: While I see why one would want to automatically update plugins, I believe there is a good reason to do it manually. After running `:BundleUpdate` you can press `u` and review the changelogs (i.e. git commit logs) of the updated plugins. From that you can learn about the new functionality introduced.

Comment: This is a *very* bad idea but the author might be interested in this "feature". Did you try the issue tracker?

Answer (score 1):

You could try calling the `:BundleUpdate` function using `vim --cmd` from a cron job (assuming you're on a Unix-like OS). On windows XP you can use [scheduled tasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569). In later versions it is called [schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx).

Note that this is probably *not* a good idea, especially for bundles in git repos. It could e.g. very well be that the bundle in question is not in a working order when you update it, leaving you with a broken plugin.

In that case you'd have to disable the automatic updating and find and check out a working version of the bundle. Not a nice thing if you're trying to get work done.

Comment: Isn't it equally true that *any* time you run the `BundleUpdate` function you risk breaking that bundle's functionality? Why is the risk of updating at regular intervals greater than the risk of updating sporadically (and manually) whenever you happen to think of doing so? Doesn't the risk of missing out on updates outweigh this risk, and isn't that why Chrome and Firefox both auto-update now?

Comment: There's *no* risk associated with missing an update of your favorite vim plugins but there are security risks associated with missing an update of your favorite browser.

Comment: @KyleStrand Updating manually allows you to inspect changes _before_ they are applied. An ounce of prevention being better than a pound of cure and all that. And it allows you to write down the last working version of a plugin in case you need to roll back.